# Mockbuild and PHP include path

Tags: php, composer-php, rpm, rpm-spec

Autoloaded a file with a path.
include-path is set on the composer.json. The include-path is appended to the app path instead of adding another path to the list.
post-install-cmd is set to trigger the vendor/bin/phpunit. It fails stating that requires is missing.
Tried to have ini_set within bootstrap/autoload.php

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required ) in /var/tmp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 58-d
```

Tried to set php -d include_path="/path/required" composer.phar update.

Neither of the solution worked. Probably I can't use ini settings, as it cannot be set while running the build within mock chroot

Here goes the verbose info

Generating optimized autoload files

> post-install-cmd: vendor/bin/phpunit
>   Executing command (CWD): vendor/bin/phpunit
>   PHP Warning:  require(/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/app/links/ConfigParser.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
>   PHP   2. require() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:34
>   PHP   3. ComposerAutoloaderInit934d343510439f54bd62ad9094992368::getLoader() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/autoload.php:7
>   PHP   4. composerRequire934d343510439f54bd62ad9094992368() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:50
>   PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/app/links/ConfigParser.inc' (include_path='/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/usr/local/stack/php:/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/app/links:/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/phpseclib/phpseclib/phpseclib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59
>   PHP Stack trace:
>   PHP   1. {main}() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
>   PHP   2. require() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:34
>   PHP   3. ComposerAutoloaderInit934d343510439f54bd62ad9094992368::getLoader() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/autoload.php:7
>   PHP   4. composerRequire934d343510439f54bd62ad9094992368() /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:50
>   Script vendor/bin/phpunit handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error

[RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Warning:  require(/builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/app/links/ConfigParser.inc): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /builddir/build/BUILD/oapp-0.2/files/usr/local/stack/php/oapp/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 59

```
{
    "name": "opt/oapp",
    "include-path": ["/usr/local/stack/php/","/app/links/"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
            "laravel/framework": "4.1.*",
            "nesbot/carbon": "1.13.*",
            "bshaffer/oauth2-server-php": "~1.6",
            "bshaffer/oauth2-server-httpfoundation-bridge": "~1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
            "classmap": [
                    "app/commands",
                    "app/controllers",
                    "app/models",
                    "app/database/migrations",
                    "app/database/seeds",
                    "app/tests/TestCase.php",
                    "app/libraries"
            ],
            "psr-4": {
                    "oapp\\": "app/oapp",
                    "oapp\\controllers\\": "app/oapp/controllers",
                    "oapp\\OAuth2\\": "app/oapp/OAuth2",
                    "oapp\\models\\": "app/oapp/models"
            },
            "files": [
                    "app/links/ConfigParser.inc"
            ]
    },
    "scripts": {
            "post-install-cmd": [
                    "vendor/bin/phpunit"
            ],
            "post-package-install": [
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                    "vendor/bin/phpunit",
             "post-create-project-cmd": [
                    "php artisan key:generate"
            ]
    },
    "config": {
            "use-include-path": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "github-protocols": ["https"]


       },
        "minimum-stability": "stable"
  }
```

Comment: can you show us your require code ? Also try using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/file"` ?

Comment: ^^ Sounds like this is running on the CLI, so `DOCUMENT_ROOT` won't be populated.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski of course, relative path then it is! `./path/file` Although I would expect a more verbose error concerning a file not found.